# Raspberry Pi Interrupts Python (GPIO Library)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, interrupt, gpio

I have a little problem with my little raspberry project, I have hooked up an LCD screen and a bunch of buttons to it, from my university course about micro-controllers I've learned that interrupts always trigger, no matter where the code is (but it was an actual microprocessor written in C). I found an "equivalent" in python, GPIO library. Normally a program is in a infinite loop waiting for an interrupt.

```
GPIO.add_event_detect(4, GPIO.RISING, callback=interrupt, bouncetime=200)
```

I set them up this way, they all go to the same method and check which button was pressed and run another method that I want (e.g one is for displaying time, another for IP address etc). A thing is, one of those methods I've done is in an infinite loop that another button press should break, but from this point a method

```
while not GPIO.event_detected(4):
```

doesn't work (calling this method in any other doesn't either if its in this loop, and all other button that I have set up will not react at all too), if it was my default while loop it does tho. I don't have much experience in either micro-controllers and python, its just hobby thing at the moment. If needed I'll share my entire code but I think its quite tangled.

Ok I am providing a simplified example, same same thing happens as in my original code. After an interrupt happens, buttons will not react, doesn't matter if I use `while not GPIO.event_detected(19)` or `GPIO.add_event_callback(26, callback=second_interrupt)`.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  # Button 1
GPIO.setup(19, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  # Button 2


def interrupt(channel):
    print "interrupt"
    if channel == 26:
        print "in loop"
        GPIO.add_event_callback(26, callback=second_interrupt)  #Trying to use this won't trigger second interrupt
        while not GPIO.event_detected(19):                      #and this wont ever trigger
            time.sleep(1)
            print "inside loop"


def second_interrupt():
    print "second interrupt"


GPIO.add_event_detect(26, GPIO.RISING, callback=interrupt, bouncetime=200)  # add rising edge detection on a channel
GPIO.add_event_detect(19, GPIO.RISING, callback=interrupt, bouncetime=200)  # add rising edge detection on a channel


while (True):
    time.sleep(1)
    if GPIO.event_detected(19):         #this version works if I wont enter an interrupt first
        second_interrupt()
```

Comment: This question is hard to answer without seeing the actual code involved.  If your code is long or tangled, the best course of action would be to create a smaller demonstration that reproduces the problem. We call this a "minimal, complete, verifiable example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and the idea is that it provides us with something to more fully understand your problem without requiring us to wade through lots of unrelated code.

Comment: I have written a simple example mimicking my original code, it does exactly the same

Comment: I'm not clear on something here: what do you expect your code to do when an interrupt is triggered on pin 19?  You've set up an event callback with `add_event_detect`, but you're also using `GPIO.event_detected` and calling a second method.  Do you intend to call both? That is, I'm not sure I understand the logic you're trying to implement.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things going on in your code. I suspect that what's really causing the problem is that you need to exit the interrupt handler before another interrupt callback can be triggered...but there is also a confusing mix of callback-based handlers *and* the `GPIO.event_detected` method.

I think you can simplify things by performing less manipulation of your interrupt configuration.  Just have a state variable that starts at 0, increment it to 1 on the first interrupt, so the next time the `interrupt` method is called you know it's the second interrupt.  No need to try setting multiple handlers like that.

Keeping in mind that I don't actually know what you're trying to do...I imagine something like this:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

state = 0

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(19, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)


def interrupt_handler(channel):
    global state

    print("interrupt handler")

    if channel == 19:
        if state == 1:
            state = 0
            print("state reset by event on pin 19")
    elif channel == 26:
        if state == 0:
            state = 1
            print("state set by event on pin 26")


GPIO.add_event_detect(26, GPIO.RISING,
                      callback=interrupt_handler,
                      bouncetime=200)

GPIO.add_event_detect(19, GPIO.RISING,
                      callback=interrupt_handler,
                      bouncetime=200)


while (True):
    time.sleep(0)
```

Comment: This is a nice answer. Why do you have `time.sleep(0)`, though?

Comment: It's been a few years, but I'm guessing that it was because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273474/behavior-of-pythons-time-sleep0-under-linux-does-it-cause-a-context-switch).